# TypeScript: Keeping track of required string literal types through concatenations in types extended from Array

Tags: typescript

Ok so, I've been switching to using Typescript. Gotta say, I like the way it spots less than obvious mistakes. But sometimes... sometimes I'm just left scratching my head wondering "What fricken sorcery is this?"

For example:

```js
/*-!!! Type declarations at the bottom. !!!-*/

/**
 * Array literal constructor with '' as first element assigned to absPath.
 */
const bobHome: absPathBob = ['', 'home', 'bob'];                  //works
const timHome: absPathTim = ['', 'home', 'tim'];                  //works

/**
 * `absPathBob` (type alias) and `absPathTime` (interface) are not quite the
 * assignable to each other, though this isn't particularly unexpected.
 */
const bobNeighbor1: absPathBob = timHome;                         //Type 'absPathTim' is not assignable to type '["", ...string[]]'.ts(2322)
const timNeighbor1: absPathTim = bobHome;                         //works

/**
 * absPath->array typecasting via spread operators should be equivalent to the
 * original array literal constructor... but isn't
 */
const bobHome2: absPathBob = [...bobHome];                        //Property '0' is missing in type 'string[]' but required in type '["", ...string[]]'.ts(2741)
const timHome2: absPathTim = [...timHome];                        //Property '0' is missing in type 'string[]' but required in type 'absPathTim'.ts(2741)

/**
 * absPath->array typecasting via concatenation should also be equivalent to the
 * original array literal constructor... but also isn't
 */
const bobHome3: absPathBob = [].concat(bobHome);                  //Property '0' is missing in type 'any[]' but required in type '["", ...string[]]'.ts(2741)
const timHome3: absPathTim = [].concat(timHome);                  //Property '0' is missing in type 'any[]' but required in type 'absPathTim'.ts(2741)

/**
 *  Relative path for concatenating onto the end of home paths.
 */
const userMusic: relPathBob = ['Multimedia', 'Music'];            //works
const userVideo: relPathTim = ['Multimedia', 'Video'];            //works

/**
 * Using spread for concatenation of absPaths with relPaths fails.
 */
const bobMusic: absPathBob = [...bobHome, ...userMusic];          //Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '["", ...string[]]'.ts(2322)
const timVideo: absPathTim = [...timHome, ...userVideo];          //Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'absPathTim'.ts(2322)

/**
 * Using Array.prototype.concat() for concatenation of absPaths with relPaths
 * also fails.
 */
const bobMusic2: absPathBob = bobHome.concat(userMusic);          //Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '["", ...string[]]'.ts(2322)
const timVideo2: absPathTim = timHome.concat(userVideo);          //Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'absPathTim'.ts(2322)

/**
 * Appending string via spread->array fails.
 */
const bobConfig: absPathBob = [...bobHome, '.config'];            //Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '["", ...string[]]'.ts(2322)
const timSSH   : absPathTim = [...timHome, '.ssh'   ];            //Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'absPathTim'.ts(2322)

/**
 * Appending string via spread->array fails.
 */
const bobConfig: absPathBob = [...bobHome, '.config'];            //Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '["", ...string[]]'.ts(2322)
const timSSH   : absPathTim = [...timHome, '.ssh'   ];            //Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'absPathTim'.ts(2322)

/**
 * A dirty hack to trick typescript works with spread operator.
 */
const bobHax1: absPathBob = ['', ...bobHome.slice(1)];            //works
const timHax1: absPathTim = ['', ...bobHome.slice(1)];            //works

/**
 * Similar dirty hack fails with Array.prototype.concat()
 */
const bobHax12: absPathBob = [''].concat(bobHome.slice(1));       //Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '["", ...string[]]'.ts(2322)
const timHax12: absPathTim = [''].concat(bobHome.slice(1));       //Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'absPathTim'.ts(2322)

/**
 * WTF? What sorcery is this?
 */
const bobHax2: absPathBob = ['', ...bobHome.slice(1), 'hax'];     //Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '["", ...string[]]'.ts(2322)
const timHax2: absPathTim = ['', ...bobHome.slice(1), 'hax'];     //Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'absPathTim'.ts(2322)

/**
 * WTF? What sorcery is this?
 */
const bobHax22: absPathBob = ['', ...bobHome.slice(1), 'hax'];     //Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '["", ...string[]]'.ts(2322)
const timHax22: absPathTim = ['', ...bobHome.slice(1), 'hax'];     //Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'absPathTim'.ts(2322)

/**
 * Array.prototype.shift() (as well as unshift, push, and pop) works fine...
 * but requires copying the absPath to a new absPath so as not to change the
 * original.
 */
const bobHax3: absPathBob = bobHome;                              //works
const timHax3: absPathTim = timHome;                              //works

bobHax3.shift();
timHax3.shift();

/**
 * Using an accumulator/for-loop pattern works.
 */
const bobLoop1: absPathBob = (() => {                              //works
    const accumulator = bobHome;
    for (let i = 0; i < userMusic.length; i++) accumulator.push(userMusic[i]);
    return accumulator;
})();

const timLoop1: absPathTim = (() => {                              //works
    const accumulator = timHome;
    for (let i = 0; i < userVideo.length; i++) accumulator.push(userVideo[i]);
    return accumulator;
})();

/**
 * But only if the accumulator starts out as an absPath
 */
const bobLoop2: absPathBob = (() => {                              //Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '["", ...string[]]'.ts(2322)
    const accumulator: string[] = []
    for (let i = 0; i < bobHome.length; i++) accumulator.push(bobHome[i]);
    for (let i = 0; i < userMusic.length; i++) accumulator.push(userMusic[i]);
    return accumulator;
})();

const timLoop2: absPathTim = (() => {                              //Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'absPathTim'.ts(2322)
    const accumulator: string[] = []
    for (let i = 0; i < bobHome.length; i++) accumulator.push(bobHome[i]);
    for (let i = 0; i < userVideo.length; i++) accumulator.push(userVideo[i]);
    return accumulator;
})();

const bobLoop3: absPathBob = (() => {                              //works
    const accumulator: absPathBob = ['']
    for (let i = 1; i < bobHome.length; i++) accumulator.push(bobHome[i]);
    for (let i = 0; i < userMusic.length; i++) accumulator.push(userMusic[i]);
    return accumulator;
})();

const timLoop3: absPathTim = (() => {                              //works
    const accumulator: absPathTim = ['']
    for (let i = 1; i < bobHome.length; i++) accumulator.push(bobHome[i]);
    for (let i = 0; i < userVideo.length; i++) accumulator.push(userVideo[i]);
    return accumulator;
})();

const bobLoop4: absPathBob = (() => {                              //Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '["", ...string[]]'.ts(2322)
    const accumulator: string[] = ['']
    for (let i = 1; i < bobHome.length; i++) accumulator.push(bobHome[i]);
    for (let i = 0; i < userMusic.length; i++) accumulator.push(userMusic[i]);
    return accumulator;
})();

const timLoop4: absPathTim = (() => {                              //Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'absPathTim'.ts(2322)
    const accumulator: string[] = ['']
    for (let i = 1; i < bobHome.length; i++) accumulator.push(bobHome[i]);
    for (let i = 0; i < userVideo.length; i++) accumulator.push(userVideo[i]);
    return accumulator;
})();



type relPathBob = [...string[]];
type absPathBob = ['', ...string[]];

interface relPathTim extends Array<string> {
    [n: number]: string;
}

interface absPathTim extends relPathTim {
    0: '';
}
```

The basic idea should be pretty straight forward. Arrays of strings are paths. Arrays of strings beginning with `''` are absolute paths. It's hardly a new idea. Given a hierarchical data structure (like the filesystem on a hard drive... or the DOM) every node has a specific path that identifies it. By adding and removing elements from the array you can "navigate" the filetree/DOM to find other nodes relative to the current one.

I've actually been using this in JavaScript for exactly such a hierarchical data structure that's part of a larger project. It's been working just fine. I thought, "huh... it'd sure be nice to have Typescript check my work at compile time and make sure I never accidentally try to use a relative path when I need an absolute path. You know... instead of littering the code with run-time type guards all over."

Well.. apparently Typescript thinks that's a terrible idea. But why?

Looking at it, it seems to have something to do with using the spread operator. I understand why one wouldn't want elements after a rest operator... but that doesn't make sense to me for spread operators. I also understand that the spread operator is using the iterable protocol, in this case, of the Array built-in... which could be the source of the problem as I was able to make it work using an accumulator/for-loop patern. So maybe it's just typescript losing track of the ['', ...]-ness of the "Home" arrays when the iterable protocal is involved... except the Hax2 example sets fire to that idea.

I'm left thinking this is either:

- a flaw in typescript's handling of spread operators
- or there's some JS compiler voodoo that typescript is keeping track of but is being super cryptic about when it tells me what I've done wrong.

Any one able to clue me in about what's going on in the examples above?

And hell, while I'm here... is there a smarter way to do this path business?

EDIT: This appears to affect Array.prototype.concat() as well. But not consistently. Nor does it affect spread operators consistently.

Comment: Obviously there are problems with spread operators in the type inference logic. A bit more smarter way that I can suggest is to use functions where you can do anything what you want with types (see `as` casting). E.g. `createAbsolutePath(root: absPath, relativePath: relPath): absPath`.

Comment: My guess about what's going on here is that the type system doesn't have a way to express "a `number` greater than `0`".  It's possible that the compiler's representation of a rest tuple like `[X, ...Y[]]` does keep track of such things internally but we can't write such a type.  Frustratingly, the error message "your thing is not assignable to my thing" doesn't contain any useful details to explain the problem; I'd be inclined to file this as a bug.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Microsoft/TypeScript#26350](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26350), [Microsoft/TypeScript#28010](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28010).

Comment: @jcalz I was leaning in that direction too but wanted to see if maybe it was just me not understanding something. Since this seems to be an actual flaw in typescript... i'll go ahead and file a report. Thanks.

Comment: Typescript issue: [Microsoft/TypeScript#30798](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30798)